# Scrapy - different download_delay for different domain

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using scrapy to download some articles from a website as well as  images within the articles.

Some info about the scenario:

- Articles come from the main domain (jandan.net)
- Images within the articles come from other websites. (e.g. tankr.net)
- Main domain has an access frequency limit so I have to set `download_delay` to avoid <403> error
- Images downloaded by `scrapy.contrib.pipeline.images.ImagesPipeline`
- Seems like the image downloading is also limited by the `download_delay` setting

How can I speed up the image download while I have to limit the download speed from main domain?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no out of the box capability for this; perhaps a some custom middleware?

Answer (score 9):

There is no public interface for it (**so my answer can become invalid in future Scrapy versions**), but you can check the implementation of the built-in [AutoThrottle](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/extensions/throttle.py) extension.

It is a bit complicated, but in Scrapy 1.0 the idea is the following: there is Downloader which handles all downloads. To decide how many requests to send in parallel and which delays to use Downloader uses "slots". By changing slot attributes (`delay`, `concurrency`) you can change Downloader behaviour.  By default, there is a slot per domain (or per IP address if [CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#std:setting-CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP) optionis set). You can also route requests to any other slot by setting a custom `request.meta['download_slot']`.

Default values for delay and concurrency for all slots are set using scrapy settings or spider attributes like `download_delay`. But you can adjust them at run time in a Scrapy extension - this is what AutoThrottle is doing. To use different download delays for different requests you need to change `delay` attribute in appropriate slots.

As your requests are sent to different domains the task is simplified - the slots are already different, you need to find them and change `delay` values. If you want to use different delays for different parts of a single website you'd have to set custom slots using `request.meta['download_slot']`.

Sorry, I won't provide a ready-to use example, but hope this helps. Feel free to ask more questions if it is unclear on where to go from this.

Also, it could be the case just enabling AutoThrottle extension is all what you need, and there is no need to write a custom extensions - try it first.

Another, simpler option is to create 2 spiders and set different download delays for them: the first downloads pages and extracts/stores links to images, the second downloads images.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is very thorough and clear, and I solved my program by customize AuthoTrottle. And here is my code: [github](https://github.com/gavinhub/Jandan.EPUB/blob/master/PaJandan/extensions/throttle.py)

Answer (score 0):

You are able to set settings per download slot, see: [Download Slot](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html?highlight=download_slot#download-slots).
To apply the documentation you would simply modify your scrapy settings.py
in the following way:

```py
DOWNLOAD_SLOTS = {
    "jandan.net": {"concurrency": 1, "delay": 2, "randomize_delay": False},
    "tankr.net": {"concurrency": 1, "delay": 3, "randomize_delay": True},
}
```

It also accepts subdomains, since you were talking of "main domain".
@Mikhail Korobov's answer is valid, but requires modification of the AutoThrottle class. It is still a good way to get familiar with extensions in scrapy.